# Selecting a property of your model and add it to your form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to take an property of my form and submit it along with my form in my Post method. I don't really need exact syntax, but I'm unsure of the logic that I would use to complete this.

Comment: Just an int variable.

Comment: ok, so u wan to submit values of ur form and form controls to controller method rite?

Comment: No I want take a property from my model, something the user enters, then put that user entry in my form.

Comment: so, u wan a view which will be model binded. i m pasting some code, like it if it helps u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model 
       `[DisplayName("User ID.")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Emailid{ get; set; }`

View

```
@model projectname.Models.modelclassname
@using (@html.beginform("Index","Home",formmethod.post)){
 @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.id)
 @html.textboxfor(model=>model.id)
 @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.name)
 @html.textboxfor(model=>model.name)
 @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.emailid)
 @html.textboxfor(model=>model.emailid)
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Controller will have post method

```
    public actionresult index(FormCollection formvalueinstance)
   {
    string id = formvalueinstance["id"];
    string name= formvalueinstance["name"];
    string emailid= formvalueinstance["idemailid];
         }
```